# .htaccess rewrite root directory forbidden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a document structure in which I have a `.htaccess` file in the parent directory called `Fort`. In that same directory, I have a folder named `public`. I have in that `public` directory a `bootstrap.php` script.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /Fort

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ bootstrap.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am using mamp and the default url is set to `localhost:8888/Fort/`.

My `bootstrap.php` script has this code:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['url'];
```

For some reason when I pass a url say `localhost:8888/Fort/foo/bar`, my `bootstrap.php` script returns the url as `foo/bar`. But if I pass the url `localhost:8888/Fort/`, I get a `403 Forbidden` error, and the `bootstrap.php` script is not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! Thanks for all the info.

Change the last line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When you visit `/Fort/` there is an empty string for the rewrite to match, and you were matching `+` which means one or more characters, when there are in fact no characters, so it wasn't getting triggered. Changing to `*` says zero or more characters which fixes the problem and will now match `/Fort/` as expected.

Comment: Now when I use that code there is not error, but instead I just get the regular apache directory root. How do I fix that so my `bootstrap.php` script can echo out things?

Comment: Try removing the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. And please accept my answer as it fixed the error you asked about.

Comment: @user249325 That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)